# Has anyone proposed an axiom for ZFC that implies that many different cardinal characteristics are distinct?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I think it is more interesting when cardinal numbers are distinct, rather than equal. Has anyone proposed an axiom for ZFC that, in one fell swoop, implies that many different [cardinal characteristics of the continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) are distinct?

Comment: There have been a few results showing that it is consistent to separate three or more particular cardinal invariants. However in general, even proving that it is consistent to separate three or more cardinals characteristics appears to be difficult. I believe the difficult lies in understanding iterated forcing of length greater than $\aleph_2$.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0367 has results on separating several cardinal characteristics at once. You may recognize one of the authors (or more, maybe). As for "more interesting", that's probably highly subjective, but there's a lot of interesting things going on when assuming forcing axioms which imply $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, and then you don't have much room for separation (or generally, any separation, since those imply Martin's axiom which generally implies equality for many cardinal characteristics).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks, looks very interesting.